# How to bring out the viewController after menu item is selected?

Tags: uitableview, menu, side-menu

Im trying to bring out the viewcontroller after i select an item in the menu. Currently, when I press something it just change the page, but it gets stuck on the right side. How do i bring that out.

This is the code that i wrote.

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

var sideMenuOpen = false
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"),
                                           object: nil)
  }

@IBOutlet weak var sideMenuConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@objc func toggleSideMenu() {
    if sideMenuOpen {
        sideMenuOpen = false
        sideMenuConstraint.constant = -270

    } else {
        sideMenuOpen = true
        sideMenuConstraint.constant = 0
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
} 

}
```

And this is what i wrote in my SideMenuVC

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
   // NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name ("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name ("ShowProfile"), object: nil)
        case 8:    //signs out of Firebase
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        //signs out of Facebook
        FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(nil)

        let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let second = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginPage")

        self.present(second, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default: break

        //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl_Re_KLhcY
    }
}
```

And this is what i wrote in my HomeVC

```
 @IBAction func menuButton() {
    print("Toggle Side Menu")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
}
```

[image]

i would like the selected page to come out.

Comment: Please add screenshots

Comment: @MumtazHussain I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name ("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)` to your didSelectRowAt